# WP PHP calling function in another file

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WP plugin, I need to call some functions of it in a different file,
`/wp-content/plugins/wolf-jplayer/includes/jplayer-show.php` has `public function head_script( $id, $playlist_id, $songs, $in_popup, $autoplay = false ) {` which I need to call in `/wp-content/themes/twentlytwelve/index.php` and then remove the function from it's original place since it's going to be in Index.php then. Is that possible? I tried everything and nothing worked.

@Niels my usage: used in wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php

```
<?php 
  $Wolf_Jplayer_Show = new Wolf_Jplayer_Shows; 
  $Wolf_Jplayer_Show->head_script( $id, $playlist_id, $songs, $in_popup, $autoplay = false ); 
 ?>
```

the function is located in wp-content/plugins/wolf-jplayer/includes/jplayer-show.php

Comment: Anyone, please? It's urgnet!!

Comment: what about define the required function as global and access it in index.php

Comment: I'm more of a PHP novice, fairly familiar with it. I don't know how to do that, makes it clear why I'm asking here. Would you be able to provide me with the code?

Comment: It's not a function, it's a class method. Assuming it does everything you need, you could just copy it into **index.php**...but my guess is that it's not going to do the job.

Comment: Yes, i tried that and just did not work.. Can whoever unreasonably down rated my question explain why he did so?

Comment: There is just way to little info to answer this, and please, do not request urgent help. People answer and vote questions on merit. I'm sorry, but *'Urgent help + not enough info' = 'No proper answers + downvotes'*

Comment: Where is that way too little info??? I described exactly what I want to do, what else is missing for you to understand??

Answer (score 1):

The function is possibly part of a class. If you keep the plugin activated you can create an instance of the class by;

```
<?php

 $the_class = new Classname;

 $the_class->function_name();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is an incomplete answer, are you willing to show me how can I use this?

Comment: Wow... I don't think you understand that everybody here is donating their own time in *trying* to help other. Your attitude is just rude at the moment. Furthermore, please edit your question with your new code, this is not readible.